# Raising an intent / opening a pdf or epub in an external viewer in rhodes (rhomobile)

Tags: android, rhomobile, rhodes

Hi is it possible to open a file in an external program from within rhodes? Open / Viewing a pdf or epub?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

> Use System.open_url : you can provide any url with any schema(http,
>   file etc), depending of platform will be run associated application to
>   handle this url

```
System.open_url('http://www.rhomobile.com')
```

It is also explained [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#run-external-application) in the Rhodes Documentation and you can find a code sample of how to do it [here](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes-system-api-samples/blob/master/app/CustomUri/controller.rb).

Answer (score 1):

```
rhodes_path = File.join(Rho::RhoApplication::get_base_app_path(), 'local/path/to/file.pdf')
System.open_url(rhodes_path)
```